# Javascript: Display multiple images at the exact same time on click, without lag between images

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, dom

I am still new to coding so please keep that in mind. I created a game to practice what I have learnt and all seemed well until I put it online and realised a significant lag in the loading of images while playing the game, specifically when the player loses or wins a level and all of the doors are meant to turn red or green. Try here:

https://moniquejb.github.io/dodge-dat-door/

Ideally I would prefer that the images wait for each other to load before displaying so that it eliminates the lag effect. Or perhaps there is an even better way that somebody can suggest. My work files are available here if necessary:

https://github.com/moniquejb/dodge-dat-door

Thanks!

Comment: Do some research regarding “image preloader” or something …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You preload them. ex: make an array of the image files

then map then to an element or something I made a little snippet for you.

Just add all the image files to the first array called imgs and then it will do loading and then provide you with an array of html img elements with the correct source etc.

```js
let imgs = [
  "https://via.placeholder.com/150",
  "https://via.placeholder.com/150",
  "https://via.placeholder.com/150",
] //all files there

preload = async(images) => {

  let load = imgs.map(async a => {
    let img = new Image()
    img.src = a
    return await new Promise(res => {
      img.onload = () => res(img)
    })


  })


  const results = await Promise.all(load)

  console.log(results)
}

preload(imgs)
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. In my game, the images that show are dependent on where the user clicks and the states of other parts of the game in that moment. Therefore the images that need to be loaded are almost always different and sometimes only one changes, sometimes four change. I am struggling to figure out how to incorporate this method in this regard, any suggestions? Thanks again!